# How to stop exit python script when other python script exits ?

Tags: python, exit

I am new to python language. My problem is I have two python scripts : Automation script A and a main script B. Script A internally calls script B. Script B exits whenever an exception is caught using sys.exit(1) functionality. Now, whenever script B exits it result in exit of script A also. Is there any way to stop exiting script A and continue its rest of execution, even if script B exits.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly **how** are you calling `scriptB`? via `import` or some sort of syscall?

Comment: I m calling script by Importing it

Answer (score 2):

You should encapsulate the code in a try except block. That will catch your exception, and continue executing script A.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This would work if script B was throwing an exception. However script B is calling sys.exit(1) in my case which causes the program to exit completely.

Comment: Except SystemExit: should catch it

Answer (score 1):

`sys.exit()` actually raises a `SystemExit` exception which is caught and handled by the Python interpreter.  All you have to do is put the call into to "script B" into a try/except block that catches `SystemExit` before it bubbles all the way up.  For example:

```
try:
    script_b.do_stuff()
except SystemExit as e:
    print('Script B exited with return code {0}'.format(e.code))
```